# Gradient of a dot product

Tags: vector-analysis, inner-products

I have two functions $\vec Q_p$ and $\vec C$, $p \in \mathbb R^3 $,

$$\vec C = \langle \theta, \alpha\rangle$$

$$\vec Q_p = \langle \sqrt{p_x^2 + p_z^2}, -p_y\rangle $$

$\theta$ and $\alpha$ are constants, you can think of $\vec C$ as the terminal side on a circle constrained to quadrant 1. And $p_x, p_y, p_z$ are the relative components of the input point p. The dot of these 2 vectors gives the distance from $\vec Q_p$ to the nearest point on the cone with the angle created by $\vec C$.

When I take the gradient of the dot of these two vector functions using the product rule, I get:

$$\nabla f_p = \langle \frac {x\theta}{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}}\vec C, -\alpha\vec C,  \frac {z\theta}{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}}\vec C\rangle $$

How is this possible? How can $\vec C$ be part of $\hat i$ and $\hat k$ in the gradient? How can I find the actual gradient?

Comment: What are $\theta$ and $\alpha$, what are $p_x,p_y,p_z$? Are functions of $x,y,z$? As stated your question as no meaning

Comment: I've updated the question @enzotib

Comment: the two vectors have two components, while the gradient has three components? Are you in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: That's the thing, we are in R3, but the calculation is done with R2 vectors because getting the distance doesn't require us to use R3 vectors. If Q was 3 component vector, the $\hat k$ would be the same as the $\hat i$ component, and the same is true for the $\vec C$ @enzotib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that this results doesn’t make sense tells you that you made a mistake in your calculation.

Taking the dot product of the constant vector $\vec{C} = ⟨θ, α⟩$ with the vector-valued function $\vec{Q}(x, y, z) = ⟨\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}, -y⟩$ gives us the scalar function
$$
  f(x, y, z) = \vec{C} ⋅ \vec{Q}(x, y, z) = θ \sqrt{x^2 + z^2} - α y \,.
$$
The partial derivatives with respect to $x$, $y$ and $z$ are
\begin{align*}
  \frac{∂ f}{∂ x}(x, y, z)
  &= \frac{θ}{2 \sqrt{x^2 + z^2}} ⋅ 2x
   = \frac{θ x}{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}} \,,
  \\[0.5em]
  \frac{∂ f}{∂ y}(x, y, z)
  &= -α \,,
  \\[0.5em]
  \frac{∂ f}{∂ z}(x, y, z)
  &= \frac{θ}{2 \sqrt{x^2 + z^2}} ⋅ 2z
   = \frac{θ z}{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}} \,.
\end{align*}
The gradient of $f$ is therefore given by
$$
  (∇f)(x, y, z)
  =
  \biggl\langle
    \frac{θ x}{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}}, \enspace
    -α, \enspace
    \frac{θ z}{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}}
  \biggr\rangle
  =
  \frac{\langle θ x, \: -α \sqrt{x^2 + z^2}, \ θ z \rangle}{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}} \,.
$$

Comment: So $\vec C$ isn't a function?

Comment: The entries $θ$ of $α$ of $\vec{C}$ are constants, so $\vec{C}$ will be a constant too.